# can we send image in push notification using this cordova plugin: cordova-plugin-fcm for mobile apps?

Tags: cordova

We are using cordova plugin i.e. cordova-plugin-fcm for sending push notification for mobile applications, But the problem is we cannot send image in push notification using this plugin. Please let me know any ideas?

Comment: what kind of image you want to send?As I know we can send the image in push plugin

Comment: Like Amazon or Flipkart sends product image in notification with some text?

Comment: have you check this issue:https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/245
and one more suggestion **https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/** is more popular then what u r using.Check the star on github

Comment: Yes, I am just try this plugin phonegap-plugin-push with ionic 1 and angularjs 1 but I got an error "PushNotification is not defined". Any idea about this...How can I resolve this error?

Comment: have you sample code with you?in you question you written that **can not send image** but here you are saying **"PushNotification is not defined"**?in this case make sure to initialize the plugin in **diviceready event**

Answer (score 1):

Another idea You can use this [OneSignal](https://github.com/OneSignal/)  Official [website](https://onesignal.com/)

you can send image **Big Picture** :

> Minimum - 512x256
>
> Balanced - 1440x720
>
> Maximum - 2880x1440

**Result** :

[image]

This Plugin it's **Free**

Comment: Nice...
But We are build hybrid app using these technologie like AngularJS 1, ionic framework 1.
OneSignal is an native based objective c or swift for iOS app and Java for Android, So how can we use in hybrid app?

Comment: yes , It supports hybrid app (Ionic .. )  check here :
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal/

Comment: Yes! can we do this using cordova-plugin-fcm? Any idea?

Comment: No idea with this plugin  .